# SSRS Report to read from 2 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I want to compare records between 2 databases on my SQL 2008 Server. The query below works in SSMS.

```
SELECT 'Manual',
       manual.*,
       'Auto',
       Auto.*
  FROM    (SELECT * FROM TESTINGSOMODS..TESTINGSOManMODS) Manual
       FULL OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT * FROM CHELTONCUSTOMIZATIONS..SOMODS) Auto
       ON manual.[Order No] = auto.fsono
```

I created a solution and when I tried to set up a shared data source, I am confronted with the following:

[image: DataSource]

So, my first question is, if I want to pull from 2 different databases what do I enter for "Select or enter a database name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it up to run from TESTINGSOMODS.  Create a stored procedure on TESTINGSOMODS that contains the query, use this procedure for the report.  The report will not know that you are accessing CHELTONCUSTOMIZATIONS, it will only look at a result set from the procedure on TESTINGSOMODS.

Comment: Please have patience as I'm new to SSRS, though I have taken a class on it. Is there no way to simply enter my SQL statement to skip creation of the datasource? 

What if I'm working with databases that I am not allowed to alter by the use of SP's? How would I accomplish this in that case?

Comment: if you can't add a stored procedure you best bet is to try using a fully qualified name, select one database as the source, then refer to each table using a complete 4 part name like: `server.database.schema.table`